# Pregunta sobre el paquete dendextend (dendogramas)

Tags: r

Estoy tratando de hacer un dendograma, lo pude hacer pero no puedo modificar el tamaño de letra de los grupos dentro del dendograma (Europe, North Dakota, ICARDA).

```
library(ggdendro)
library(ggplot2)
library(dendextend)

data1 %>% 
  scale %>% 
  dist %>% 
  hclust(method = "ward.D2") %>% 
  as.dendrogram


dend %>% 
   set("branches_k_color", value = c("red", "blue", "green"), k = 3, groupLabels = c("Europe", "North Dakota", "ICARDA")) %>% 
   set("labels_cex", c(0.2)) %>% set("labels_cex", c(0.2)) %>% set("branches_lwd", 0.2) %>% plot(ylab = "Height")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]